# Using Discord's 'message' listener on other files

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to use commands like `message.delete();` in functions from other files. Is there a way to add listeners without the `client.on()` method?
I.E.

index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', async message => {
//stuff here like message.delete(); or message.channel.send();
});
```

And I would like to use it like

example.js

```
const message = somehow add the listener?

message.delete();
message.author.sen();
```

Comment: provide your code snippet so that people can help

Comment: I don't really have a code since I don't know how to do the stuff but I edited it in a way that I belive it'll make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may export your variables with an handler. https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/